# taking arguments from command line and putting them in regular expression statments

Tags: c

The task is
Make a program that reads from text file and write to other text file
only symbols that are given in command line args 
example:
program a-z in.txt out.txt

will write to file out.txt only letters that are in a-z range nothing more.
program a-9 in.txt out.txt
will write to file out.txt only letters that are in a-z0-9 range nothing more.
It can be assumed that all entered data are correct.

so here is my attempt:

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
    FILE *fileIn, *fileOut;
    fileIn = fopen(argv[2] , "rb");
    fileOut = fopen(argv[3] , "wb");
    char *arguments = argv[1];

    printf("%d - %d\n", arguments[0], arguments[2]);
    char a;
    do 
    {
        a = fgetc(fileIn);
        if( a > arguments[0] && a < arguments[2])
            fputc(a, fileOut);  
    } while (a != EOF);

    fclose(fileIn);
    fclose(fileOut);
    return 0;
 }
```

my first idea was to take args and use them as ascii limiters
it somehow works on a-z but with other it dosn't
the question is:
how i can improve this?
should i change the way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will modify your `if` statement to something like following:

```
if(arguments[2] >= '0' && arguments[2] <= '9') {
   if((a >= arguments[0] && a <= arguments[0]) || (a >= '0' && a <= arguments[2]))  
   {
      fputc(a, fileout);
   }
}
else if(arguments[2] >= 'a' && arguments[2] <= 'z' && arguments[0] >= 'a' && arguments[0] <= 'z') {
   if(a >= arguments[0] && a <= arguments[2]) {
      fputc(a, fileout);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is what I could not come up with, work's like a charm thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you give `a-9` as the argument, the program won't work correctly because the ascii code values for numeric letters (`'0'` to `'9'`) are all smaller than those for lowercase roman alphabets (`'a'` to `'z'`).

For example, the value of `'0'` is 0x30 ('1' is 0x31 and so on), and 'a' is 0x61 ('b' is 0x62, and so on), so an if statement with the condition `(a >= 'a' && a <= '9')` will not be executed at all.

And the condition expression of your `if` statement will evaluate to `0` when the char being tested equals `argument[0]` or `argument[2]`. You might want to change that.